# Laravel - Como tratar un enumerador

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-8

Tengo un modelo que se llama **Receta** y tiene un atributo que es **tiempo de coccion** y puede contener estos valores : "menosde5min", "entre5y15min","masde15min".

Ahora mismo tengo montado en una vista con blade un radio button donde recibo estos valores y almaceno estos valores en la BD.

Pero cuando recupero estos valores para mostrarlos quiero que "menosde5min" muestre por pantalla "Menos de 15min".

Cuando recupero los atributos del modelo me devuelve "menosde5min", entonces no se cual es la mejor opción para tratar esto, si hacer uso de un "adaptar" y alli tratar los datos?

Actualmente el modelo "Receta" tiene esta estructura.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Receta extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'recetas';

   protected $guarded = ['id'];

   public function autor()
   {
      return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','user_id');
   }
}
```

He probado a añadirle esta relación al modelo y luego cada vez que lo recupero debo hacer algo tipo esto

```
$label = $receta->tiempoCoccion()->tiempo_coccion_texto;


    public function tiempoCoccion()
{
    if ($this->tiempoCocina === 'menos15min') {
        $this->tiempo_coccion_texto = 'Menos de 15 minutos';
    }
    else if ($this->tiempoCocina === 'entre15y30min') {
        $this->tiempo_coccion_texto = 'Entre 15 y 30 minutos';
    }
    else if ($this->tiempoCocina === 'entre30y60min') {
        $this->tiempo_coccion_texto = 'Entre 30 y 60 minutos';
    }
    else if ($this->tiempoCocina === 'entre1y2horas') {
        $this->tiempo_coccion_texto = 'Entre 1 y 2 horas';
    }
    else if ($this->tiempoCocina === 'mas2horas') {
        $this->tiempo_coccion_texto = 'Más de 2 horas';
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Espero vuestros consejos.

Answer (score 2):

Tu método `tiempoCoccion` devuelve `$this` y asigna la propiedad  `tiempo_coccion_texto` como un side effect, de manera que otro método puede modificarla sin dejar huella entre que la calculas y la imprimes por pantalla.

Eloquent te permite definir que un método sea invocado al acceder una propiedad imaginaria, y con eso se vuelve una función del tiempo de cocción, en vez de quedar dando vueltas a la deriva.

```
public function getTiempoCoccionTextoAttribute() {

    if ($this->tiempoCocina === 'menos15min') {
       return  'Menos de 15 minutos';
    }
    if ($this->tiempoCocina === 'entre15y30min') {
       return 'Entre 15 y 30 minutos';
    }
    ... más de lo mismo...
    return 'más de 2 horas';
}
```

Con eso `$receta->tiempo_coccion_texto` devolverá lo que buscas.

*De paso, fíjate que no hace falta meter `else if` en este cuento. Si la condición se cumple retornas y sales del método. Si no se cumple pasas al siguiente. Si ninguno se cumple hay un return al final.*

Pero, volviendo a nuestro atributo, puedes definir que la propiedad venga en el resultado sin tener que pedirla, como si fuese un campo de la tabla subyacente, usando la propiedad `$appends` del modelo

```
 protected $appends = [
    'tiempo_coccion_texto'
 ];
```

`tiempo_coccion_texto` vendrá en cualquier consulta que incluya al modelo  `Receta`.

También  es una práctica usual ocupar un array como diccionario:

```
public static $tiempos_diccionario=[
    'menos15min'=> 'Menos de 15 minutos',
    'entre15y30min'=> 'Entre 15 y 30 minutos',
    'entre30y60min'=> 'Entre 30 y 60 minutos',
    'entre1y2horas'=> 'Entre 1 y 2 horas'
];

public function getTiempoCoccionTextoAttribute() {
     return self::$tiempos_diccionario[$this->tiempo_coccion]
            ?? 'Más de 2 horas';
}
```

Y, para cortar por lo sano, también es buena idea usar constantes para esas llaves de texto.

```
    const MENOS15MIN = 'menos15min';
    const ENTRE15Y30MIN = 'entre15y30min';
    const ENTRE30Y60MIN = 'entre30y60min';
    const ENTRE1Y2HORAS = 'entre1y2horas';
    const MAS2HORAS = 'mas2horas';

 public static $tiempos_diccionario = [
    MENOS15MIN => 'Menos de 15 minutos',
    ENTRE15Y30MIN => 'Entre 15 y 30 minutos',
    ENTRE30Y60MIN => 'Entre 30 y 60 minutos',
    ENTRE1Y2HORAS => 'Entre 1 y 2 horas',
    MAS2HORAS => 'Más de 2 horas'
 ];
```

Porque, si necesitas usar esa nomenclatura en otras partes del código, puedes usar siempre `Receta::ENTRE15Y30MIN` (por ejemplo) en vez de depender de un string que el día de mañana puedes cambiar en un lugar y olvidar en el otro.

---

Hay otro enfoque que permite solucionar esto usando una relación con una tabla `tiempos_coccion`, cuya llave primaria fuera '`entre30y60min`', '`entre1y2horas`', etc. Depende de tu lógica de dominio si vale la pena definir un modelo para esto. Si se trata de una cuestión de formato para la capa de presentación, me parece que es más lo que confunde que lo que aporta.

Permite asegurar la integridad relacional, sí, pero estarás solucionando con la base de datos algo que para la base de datos es irrelevante. Por el contrario, en tu capa de negocios PHP ya no podrá detectar errores o inconsistencias estáticamente. Le habrá cedido el control de un problema suyo a una capa distinta y hasta que ella responda no hay más que cruzar los dedos.

---

Para nuestros distinguidos lectores puede ser útil saber que los enums son, junto con los structs (o en su defecto, declaraciones de tipo que no sean un saludo a la bandera en los docblocks) una de las grandes deudas de PHP que contribuyen a su fama de frágil.

Al menos con los enum, es un constructo que viene en PHP 8.1

```
enum TiempoCoccion: string
{
    case entre1y2horas = 'Entre 1 y 2 horas';
    case mas2horas = 'Más de 2 horas';
    case entre30y60min = 'Entre 30 y 60 minutos';
}
```

El constructo es mucho más profundo que ese ejemplo, pero lo que aparentemente podría hacerse con arrays y constantes como sugerí más arriba, con esta mejora permite (opcionalmente) usar una declaración de tipo. Ese enum no admite más que strings, y eso es un mundo de diferencia.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, ahora si !!! 1000 gracias